# Text "jumping/shaking" in input when changing size in Firefox (Mac)

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I am working on a project where we showcase fonts, and users can try them and change the size, spacing with sliders.

Everything works beautifully on Chrome and Safari, however in Firefox the text jumps up and down in the input as it changes in size

[image]

It seems to jump in regular intervals tho.

**Edit**

I stripped down my original code and here is the relevant one. It "jumps" when I play with it in Firefox.

```js
// start
window.onload = setup;

function setup() {
  sliderEventAssign("size-slider", fontSizeEvent);
}

// event handlers
function fontSizeEvent(event) {
  var path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
  var root = path[3];
  var value = round(event.target.value);

  // update size value
  root.getElementsByClassName("font-preview")[0].style.fontSize = value + "px";
  root.getElementsByClassName("size-value")[0].innerText = value + " px";
}


// utils
function sliderEventAssign(selector, handler) {
  var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName(selector);
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('input', handler, false);
  });
}

function round(a) {
  return Math.round(a * 100) / 100;
}
```

```css
.interactive-font {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:20px;
    min-height: 670px;
}

.interactive-font span, .interactive-font p {
    cursor: default;
}

.tools {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 180px 240px 1fr 212px 145px 2fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
    margin: auto 10px;
}

.shown .slider-wrapper {
    display: block !important;
}


.font-preview {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 250px;
    display: block;
  font-family: serif;
    border:none;
    background-image:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.font-preview::selection {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.slider-value {
  width: 80px;
  align-self: center;
}

.size-slider {
    width: 140px;
}

input:focus, button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
   <div id="FontName" class="interactive-font">
        <div class="tools">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <input type="range" min="16" max="400" value="250" step="1" 
                       class="slider size-slider" />
                <span class="size-value slider-value">250 px</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="text-field">
            <input class="font-preview" 
                   type="text" value="Hello" 
                   spellcheck="false"
                   style="font-size: 250px;"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also noticed this problem exists with `serif` but not `sans-serif`

Do you have any clue what might cause this? I tried setting line-height, and somehow fixing it to bottom (that did not help)?

**EDIT2**

I will add a video how it looks in this example above on my computer.
I use Firefox 90.0.2 on macOs 10.15.6 (MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019))

[image]

Comment: Could you show us a complete snippet so we can see for ourselves - in particular how are you changing the font-size?

Comment: @AHaworth I added an example

Answer (score 0):

I tried an experiment with a CSS animation as font-size is supposed to be an animatable property.

If anything Firefox (on Windows10) is smoother than Chrome, which occasionally shows an almost imperceptible jump in size (probably a pixel's worth, but I don't know).

```css
.font {
  font-family: serif;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 250px;
  border: none;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    font-size: 250px;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="font" value="Some text" />
```

There isn't anything setting animation steps in your code is there?

Comment: I changed the text to an input here, and after like 10-15 seconds it start jumping in your example too! Edit: I refreshed the page and could not reproduce it tho.

Comment: I tried your example on FF and Chrome and couldn't get jumping. How are you animating in your snippet - is it just the user sliding the slider up and down (which I did - both very fast and very slow).

Comment: yes I just use the slider. Maybe this is only an issue on firefox and mac? Or just a specific version? however very very strange. The gif I added to the question shows how it looks on my computer.

Comment: Maybe it is an FF + Mac problem. FF+Windows10 is OK for me. Weird though.